# Windows 8 wscript.exe not running *.vbs files

Tags: windows-8, vbscript

I've had Windows 8 running fine on my work PC for several months, but today when I booted it up, it would not run my *.vbs logon scripts.

> There is no script engine for file extension ".vbs".

I first tried the obvious, and have since done a fair amount of Google searches. Here is a list of all of the actions that I have carried out.

- Restarted my computer (you never know).
- Check that `C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe` exists, which it did.
- Set the program default by right clicking, selecting 'Open with -> Choose default program...' and choosing `Microsoft Windows Based Script Host`.
- Set the association through 'Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs -> Set Associations'. As expected, this was already correct due to the action above.
- Register `vbscript.dll` by clicking 'Start -> Run -> type "regsvr32.exe vbscript.dll"'.

After all of these actions, I am still receiving the same error message. Can someone please help with a suggestion as to what I should do next? Thanks.

Comment: Have you attempted to run the file manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here was to restore the settings in the registry. I found a script to do that here - http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html

It says that it is for Windows 7, but in this instance, it worked fine for Windows 8.